# Javascript remote object skipping a decimal when this is 0

Tags: apex, remote-action, remote-objects

I am using remote object to bring some values into a VF page, basically the user as it types it calculates and update the opportunity, so the remote is "constantly" updating the page.

Then I have a javascript that perform some extras, everything works fine, except when the second decimal is a 0, then this decimal is skipped when the remote brings it into the page and "injects it into the JS"

So for instance

```
Format Text:        
<apex:outputText value="{0, number,$ ###,###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Weekly_Repayment__c}" />
</apex:outputText>   
<br />
Non Format: {!Opportunity.Weekly_Repayment__c}
```

is shown as:

[image: Error in result]

inmediatly a javascript its calculated with 8 cents and not 80

is there a way to tell the remote that it is 2 decimals? without actually having to do weird tricks in the js to get this fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.8 == 0.80`. They both mean "80 cents". In your JavaScript, use the `Number#toFixed` method:

```
var myCurrency = sourceValue.toFixed(2);
```